# Overflow causing the hover menu display and its cutting not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

CSS:

```
.main{
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    background: #ccc;
    min-height: 500px;
    position: relative;
}

.inner{
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: blueviolet;
    left: 200px;
    display: none;
}

.menu{
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding:0px 0 0 10px;
}

.main .menu:hover >.inner{display: block !important;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
  <a href="#" class="menu">Menu  <div class="inner"></div> </a>
</div>
```

help me if Anyone can...

Please find [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kTKG5/)

Comment: <div class="main">
      
        <a href="#" class="menu">Menu  <div class="inner"></div> </a>

    </div>

Comment: Explain what is your requirement properlly

Comment: Also find the fiddle for your question: http://jsfiddle.net/kTKG5/

Comment: still not displaying the hover box fully its cutting or hiding by parent div

Comment: @ankur what u did the change in above ur provided fiddle

Comment: issue is that when i remove the overflow property from main class this is showing up but i need the overflow property for big table that have many rows and columns in that case i can use the scroll so any one can help me without removing the overflow:scroll property to main class and show the perfect div inner

Comment: I have not changed any value... I have just copied your code and pasted on the fiddle.

Comment: @Ankur140290 .... on menu hover its not showing up http://jsfiddle.net/kTKG5/2/

Comment: That's not my fiddle. Check the link: http://jsfiddle.net/kTKG5/

Answer (score 0):

i have doubt,  why you putting css top: -20px;,
if u change top:0; visible correctly

Comment: i think not possible in css, but it possible with using jQuery